# regex comma before space and number

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to search for every comma before space and a number to remove it.

This is what I have:

```
Mustardroad, 21, Teststreet 2, Point Place, 5
```

And this is what I want:

```
Mustardroad 21, Teststreet 2, Point Place 5
```

Comment: with something like this : `/, [0-9]{1,}/g` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$res = preg_replace('/,\s+(?=\d)/', '', $string);
```

This will remove every comma and following spaces before a digit by nothing.

If you want to keep one space before the digit:

```
$res = preg_replace('/,\s+(?=\d)/', ' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `preg_replace` function with specific regex pattern:

```
$str = 'Mustardroad, 21, Teststreet 2, Point Place, 5';
$str = preg_replace("/,(?=\s+\d)/", "", $str);

print_r($str);
```

The output:

```
Mustardroad 21, Teststreet 2, Point Place 5
```

---

`(?=\s+\d)` - lookahead positive assertion, ensures that a comma `,` is followed by "*space and a number*"

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, you can do:

```
$str = 'Mustardroad, 21, Teststreet 2, Point Place, 5';

$result = array_reduce(explode(', ', $str), function ($c,$i) {
    if (empty($c))
        return $i;
    return is_numeric($i[0]) ? "$c $i" : "$c, $i";
});
```

With `preg_replace`: see @Roman or @Toto answers. *(eventually with a literal space instead of `\s+`, if it is what you want)*